# Tag specific ranking for Stack Overflow

Tags: support, tags, users

Is it possible to get a tag specific ranking of a user profile in Stack Overflow? In other words, I want to check if I could relatively evaluate a user with respect to certain tags like python, java or c++.

Comment: Look at their profile and you can see how many questions they have answered for a certain tag. Is this a programming question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can go to the user's profile, click on the Tags heading, then you'll see the list of tags.  The score they have in the tag is in front of that tag.  Hover over that for more information.

[image: Tag Score]

BUT, unless they're in the top 20, you won't be able to see a relative ranking for them in that tag.